# Procing that If $A_j,j\in J$ are connected then $\bigcup_{j\in J} A_j$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, connectedness

In an exercise I am asked to prove the following statement:

> Let $\{A_j:j\in J\}$ be a family of connected subspaces of a topological space $(X,\tau)$. If $\bigcap\limits_{j\in J}A_j \neq \emptyset$, then $\bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j$ is connected.

I was able to prove this, but I think that I complicated it making my proof a little bit convoluted and I'm a little skeptical about it. When I read It I can't spot any mistakes but maybe I am missing something. This is my proof:

---

Let $\tau '$ be the topology induced by $(X,\tau)$ in $\bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j$. The proof is by contradiction, so let's suppose that $\exists C,D \in \tau': C \cap D = \emptyset$ and $C\cup D = \bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j$. So we have that:

$$C = C^* \cap \bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j$$
$$D = D^* \cap \bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j$$

With , $C^*,D^* \in \tau$. We know that $C \cap D = \emptyset$. This is the same as saying:

$$\begin{align}
& C^* \cap \bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j \cap D^* \cap \bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j=\\
= & \bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j \cap C^* \cap D^* = \emptyset \ \ \ (1)
\end{align}$$

We know that $C^* \cap \bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j \neq \emptyset$ and $D^* \cap \bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j \neq \emptyset$, so from equation (1) we take that $C^* \cap D^* = \emptyset$.

Now, we know that $C \cup D = \bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j$. We can write $C \cup D$ as:

$$\begin{align}
& \left[C^* \cap \bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j\right] \cup \left[D^* \cap \bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j\right]= \\
\\
= & \left[\bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j\right] \cap \underbrace{\left[\bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j \cup C^*\right] \cap \left[\bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j\cup D^*\right]}_{\underbrace{(C^* \cap D^*)}_\emptyset \cup \bigcup_{j \in J}A_j} \cap \left[C^* \cup D^*\right]\\
\\
= & \left[\bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j\right] \cap \left[\bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j\right] \cap [C^* \cup D^*]\\
\\
= & \left[\bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j\right] \cap [C^* \cup D^*]
\end{align}$$

So we end up with: $$\left[\bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j\right] \cap [C^* \cup D^*] = \bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j$$ because $C \cup D = \bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j$.

This means that $$\bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j \subseteq C^* \cup D^*$$

So now let's define the following sets:

$$C_1 = C^* \cap A_1$$
$$D_1 = D^* \cap A_1$$

Now, both $C_1$ and $D_1$ are open in $A_1$. we have that $C_1 \cap D_1 = \emptyset$ as $C^* \cap D^* = \emptyset$ and we know that $C_1 \cup D_1 = A_1$ as $A_1 \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j \subseteq C^* \cup D^*$. So we conclude that $A_1$ is not connected. This is a contradiction, and so $\bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j$ can't be disconnected.

---

Is my proof correct and valid or did I made some mistake that I'm not aware of?

P.s.: I know that there is another question regarding this problem but this post is different for the simple fact that I'm asking for a validation of my specific way of solving it.

Comment: Hint for writing a more elegant proof: a topological space $X$ is not connected if and only if there exists a surjective continuous map $X \to 2$, where $2$ is the discrete space on two points. Show that if $\bigcup_{j \in J} A_j$ is not connected, then $\bigcap_{j \in J} A_j = \varnothing$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a mistake in your proof.

(there is also a minor typo in the beginning:
You write $C\cap D = \bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j$,
but you mean $C\cup D = \bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j$.)

The mistake occurs when applying (1) to conclude that $C^*\cap D^* =\emptyset$.
We define $E:=\bigcup\limits_{j\in J}A_j$.
Your argument seems to be that $C^*\cap D^* =\emptyset$
follows from the three arguments
$C^*\cap E\neq\emptyset$,
$D^*\cap E\neq\emptyset$,
$C^*\cap D^*\cap E=\emptyset$.

However, in general this does not need to be the case.
A counterexample to this argument is
$C^*=\{1,2\}, D^*=\{1,3\}, E=\{2,3\}$.

Comment: You are right. Then what conclusion can I take about $C^* \cap D^*$?

Comment: I would suggest working in $\tau'$ and not $\tau$. But I am not sure if this works. You could also try the hint from diracdeltafunk.